# Redirect /map/ to /file.php if /map/ does not exist using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect users from `www.hostname.com/map/` to `www.hostname.com/map.php` if `/map/` does not exists. I have the following .htaccess file already:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Which does the following:

- Redirect users automatically to the `https://` variant of my website
- Redirects `/filename` to `/filename.php` if there is no map called `/filename/` without changing the visible url

But now I want to redirect users from `/map/` to a file called `/map`.php as well if there is no map called `/map/`. Ofcourse I don't want to display the `.php` portion of the file name, so I basically want users to be redirected to `/filename` if the map `/filename/` does not exists without changing the visible url. How can I rewrite the code above to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# keep redirect rule before internal routing one
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# if matching .php file exists forward it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @anubhava What about checking if an index.php file exists in a directory?

Comment: No need to check for `index.php` because directories are anyway being skipped from above rule.